# How to put computer to sleep using subprocess.call?

Tags: python, windows, shutdown, sleep-mode

I'm in the middle of making a Python script to shutdown, restart, hibernate or put to sleep after a few seconds.

I know its `subprocess.call(["shutdown", "/s"])` to shutdown, `"/r"` to restart and `"/h"` to hibernate.

How can you put the computer to sleep using `call()` on Windows 10?

Comment: `shutdown -s` is the command on windows and you can add the `-t` param to give a time in seconds like `60` for a minute

Answer (score 2):

Shutdown doesn't have a function for Sleep integrated however you can use the following: `rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0`

Comment: Do i use this with subprocess.call ?

Comment: Yes, that's propably the easiest way.

Comment: Could you please write it out for me ? I'm having trouble with the syntax.
thanks

Comment: It seems that this just returns 0 and does nothing more

Answer (score 1):

I know this is asked 3 years ago, but if anyone looking for help, I found a way for sleep with [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

First download and install pyautogui with terminal using command **pip download pyautogui** and **pip install pyautogui**

1. Import it

> import pyautogui

2. use this code (change if you need)

> ```
> pyautogui.hotkey("alt", "f4")
> time.sleep(1)
> pyautogui.press("left")
> time.sleep(1)
> pyautogui.press("enter")
> ```

[Visit this website if you need any help with pyautogui commands](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)

(I am too new to python coding, there must be easy and more suitable ways to do this. Sorry if I sound so noob.)